# C++ user defined class gives compilation error with unordered set

Tags: c++, unordered-set

I have structure called NodeID. When I create the unordered_set for this, I get the following compilation error

Error   C2678   binary '<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const _Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <map>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

struct NodeID
{
  // Constructor
  NodeID();

  int mRgnID;
  unsigned int mGID;

  // Equal operator
  bool operator == ( const NodeID& rhs ) const;

  // Less than operator
  bool operator < ( const NodeID& rhs ) const;


  size_t operator()( const NodeID& n ) const noexcept 
  {
    return n.mGID;
  };
};


NodeID::NodeID()
{
  mRgnID = -1;
  mGID = 0;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Function : operator ==
// Purpose  : Equal operator
bool NodeID::operator == ( const NodeID& rhs ) const
{
  if (mRgnID != rhs.mRgnID)
    return false;

  if (mGID != rhs.mGID)
    return false;

  return true;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Function : operator <
// Purpose  : Less than operator
bool NodeID::operator < ( const NodeID & rhs ) const
{
  if (mRgnID < rhs.mRgnID)
    return true;
  else if (mRgnID > rhs.mRgnID)
    return false;
  else
  {
    if (mGID < rhs.mGID)
      return true;
    else if (mGID > rhs.mGID)
      return false;
  }
  return false;
}

namespace std {
  template<>
  struct hash<NodeID>
  {
    std::size_t operator()( const NodeID& p ) const
    {
      return hash<int>()(p.mGID);
    }
  };
}


typedef std::unordered_set<NodeID> NodeSet;

int main()
{
  NodeSet s;
  NodeID n;
  n.mGID = 2;
  n.mRgnID = 0;
  s.insert( n );

  std::map<NodeSet, int> m;
  m.insert( std::make_pair(s, 1) );
}
```

I have defined the less than operator in the NodeID structure

Comment: BTW, `unordered_*` doesn't use `operator <` (but hash and `==`).

Comment: I have edited my code. May is this because due to the map Im using which is taking the unordered_set as key???

Comment: Sure Let me provide the reproduceable code..

Comment: I think now the above shown code should be able to give the error message ...

Comment: IF I change the typedef std::unordered_set<NodeID> NodeSet;
 to typedef std::set<NodeID> NodeSet; then its working fine. So std::set has implmented the < operator where as std::unordered_set does not. Is there any way I can have unordered_set as a key in std::map??

Comment: @user6771624 `std::map` uses `operator<` by default to order its keys, but `std::unordered_set` does not implement `operator<` (but `std::set` does, yes).  So, either implement your own `operator<` for `NodeSet` as a standalone function, or else create a custom comparator to use with the 3rd template argument of `std::map`. Otherwise, use `std::unordered_map` instead, which uses hashes instead of `operator<`.

Comment: Thats how earlier it was implemented where NodeSet is defined as std::set. But this is used in many other places ( huge nodesets) apart from used in some map as key. So I thought of changing to unordered_set to optimize the code..But looks like I cant use unordered_set as my key unless i define the < operator. But what should go into the < operator of Nodeset?

Comment: @user6771624 That is for you to decide in your implementation. What makes sense to you when comparing two `NodeSet`s for less-than? Probably compare their `size()`'s first. If `left` has fewer than `right`, return `true`. If `right` has fewer than `left`, return `false`. Otherwise, if equal then iterate them checking `<` for each `NodeID` until one of them returns `true`. Of course, they are unordered, after all... So figure out something that works for you.